Android develop: How to make app not cover/change the top status bar?
I am new in developing android app.
I now have this in themes.xml:
<style name="Theme.blablabla" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

And in AndroidManifest.xml:
android:theme="@style/Theme.blablabla"

I want the top status bar not be change by this app (leave it as no app display on the phone).
How can I do? By the way, I tried remove the upper mentioned line in AndroidManifest.xml.
But I got this fatel error when running this app:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:212)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:147)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:114)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:145)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:113)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:108)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:103)


(leave it as is when no app display on the phone) what do u mean by this?

Please clarify your actual problem and observe the meaning of your goal statement, such as, leave it as is when no app display on the phone, did you mean... leave it as is when an app is being displayed on the phone?

@Rakesh Rebbavarapu
I have changed this sentence.

@DevQt
I mean leave it(the very top status bar) as no app display on the phone

If you don't want to hide the status bar, you just have to modify the parent of theme set in the themes.xml file.
Your current theme:
<style name="Theme.blablabla" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

As you can see the parent attribute in here, there is Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar. The NoActionBar thing is hiding the status bar when your app is opened.
Change it to:
<style name="Theme.blablabla" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

This will not hide the status bar.
Or shortly, just remove the NoActionBar thing from the parent attribute from the theme.

you are confusing status bar (very top of the device) with ActionBar/Toolbar (very top of app, below status)

@snachmsm
Yes. I mean status bar (very top of the device).

your advice is to show/hide ActionBar/Toolbar, which isn't related to status bar at all (besides they are neighbors on screen)

@yuexia_wrp is it possible for your provide screenshot/design of what u want?

In your app\build.gradle
You have to set minSdkVersion to 27 because the following configuration needs to have minSdkVersion 27.
Then you can use this setup.
<style name="Theme.blablabla" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">never</item>
    </style>

NOTE: Use the above theme configuration on other pages of your app as well.
To test:
<style name="Theme.blablabla" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">never</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" >@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

I observed that setting statusBarColor to white has no effect now.
NOTE: Please don't mind the theme appearance of the status bar (unless you want to customize it) because Android OS itself forced a default theme for that.
